# Adding line space in output of php code

Tags: php, line, space

I have php code to print two tables continuously. But border of first table coincide with the border of second table. How can I give space between them. echo "\n" , echo ("\r\n"); echo ("\r"); are not  helping.

Answer (score 3):

You should use css with the second table (or first)

```
.yourTable {margin-top: 10px;}
```

Or the quick, dirty and the wrong solution: just print a `<p>` between the tables

Answer (score 1):

`echo '<br/>';` or you can use CSS

Answer (score 0):

With CSS `margin` or add a `<br/>`